# Adding up using cricket notation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm wanting to work out how I might go about summing the number of overs I've bowled throughout my career (yes, I am serious enough about it to have a stats spreadsheet), with similar functionality to the SUMIF() function, though the critical flaw with that function in this regard is how it deals with cricket notation. For example, if I had these stats in three matches:
3.4 overs bowled, 5.0 overs bowled, 2.3 overs bowled
SUMIF() would sum those to equal 3.4+5.0+2.3=10.7, whereas I want it to equal 11.1 overs. The reason I want to keep the SUMIF() functionality is that I want to be able to sum the number of overs according to which team I played for or against. This is for the "Total Overs" column in the below screenshot:
[image]

I've currently got a SUMIF() in my spreadsheet as a make-do, because I'm lucky enough to have only ever bowled full overs. However I know this won't work forever, so I'd like to have a solution for it before I need it. I've got a formula for converting the number of overs into number of deliveries, but I don't know how to convert the other way, so summing the number of deliveries won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can you try:*

```js
=let(Σ,split(sumif(A:A,F2,C:C),"."), Λ,index(Σ,,1)*6 + iferror(index(Σ,,2)),     
    trunc(Λ/6,)+mod(Λ,6)/10)
```

[image]

**breakup**:

*sumif value*: `10.7`

*coverting it to balls*: `(10*6)+7 = 67`

*converting `67` to overs:* =truncated value of `67/6 = 11` + `mod(67,6)/10 = 0.1` = `11.1`

Comment: Yes, thank you, this works perfectly. If you wouldn't mind, would you be able to explain what each bit of the formula is doing, as I'd like to be able to answer fairly basic questions such as this in future without having to ask other people.

Comment: Added explanation to the answer.